# TreeItem selection width in a TreeView

Tags: treeview, javafx-2, javafx-8, treeviewitem, treecellrenderer

I'm using JavaFX 8 and I'm currently doing some GUI developments. I have a little problem with my TreeView and I need your help.

Do you know if it is possible, in a TreeView, to select just the label and not the whole width of the TreeCell ?

I mean (Netbeans example) :

[image: Good TreeView selection]

Instead of :

[image: Bad TreeView selection]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the "look" can be achieved via styling (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28113294/203657 or more precisely: the accepted answer) - but that'll still leaves the "feel" open - needs some work to ignore mouse-event outside the label

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding a Label inside TreeCell.
for example:

```
private static class YourItemCell extends TreeCell<YourItem>
{
    Label label;

    public YourItemCell()
    {
        label = new Label();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(YourItem item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty && item != null)
        {
            label.setText(item.getText());
            setGraphic(label);
        }
    }
}
```

If you return the cell using the "TreeView.setCellFactory" method, it's okay.