# JavaFX-CSS: How to "move" style of parent to a child?

Tags: java, javafx-8, treecell, javafx-css

The trigger for this was a quick experiment to solve [TreeItem selection width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23792004/203657): the requirement is to highlight only the text, not the whole tree cell. Nothing easier than that (said Frederik :)

- implement a custom TreeCell with a Label as graphic (and configure the label with the item as needed)
- remove the selection style (mostly the highlight background from the cell
- add the highlight style to the label

Something like (a runnable example using this is at the end):

```
public static class MyTreeCell extends TreeCell<String> {

    private Label label;

    public MyTreeCell() {
        getStyleClass().add("tree-text-only");
    }
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (label == null) {
                label = new Label();
            }
            label.setText(item);
            setGraphic(label);
        }
    }
}
```

The css:

```
/* remove the highlight from cell as a whole, 
   c&p'd the unselected style from modena */
.tree-text-only:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background; 
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
}
/* c&p'd selected style */
/* using > doesn't make a different to the behaviour */ 
/* .tree-text-only:filled:selected > .label { */

.tree-text-only:filled:selected .label {
    /* following is the selection color from themes, doesn't show */
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar; 
    /* hard-coded color does show */
    /*   -fx-background-color: -fx-accent ; */
    /* auto-adjust text fill */
    /* no effect for hard-coded color, showing nothing for selection bar */
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}
```

Expected behaviour

- label has highlighted background when using selection-bar
- text auto-adjusts its fill

Actual behaviour:

- using the "semantic" (?) highlight color selection-bar, the background color of the label is not changed to the highlight color but the text fill is changed to the "white", so the text doesn't show
- using a hard-coded color (any, even the accent as above) changes the label's background but the text fill isn't updated

The obvious question: How to make it work as expected?

For convenience, a runnable example:

```
public class TreeCellExample extends Application {

    public static class MyTreeCell extends TreeCell<String> {

        private Label label;

        public MyTreeCell() {
            getStyleClass().add("tree-text-only");
        }
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (label == null) {
                    label = new Label();
                }
                label.setText(item);
                setGraphic(label);
            }
        }
    }

    private Parent getContent() {
        TreeItem root = createSubTree("root");
        root.setExpanded(true);
        TreeView tree = new TreeView(root);
        tree.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource("treetextonly.css").toExternalForm());
        tree.setCellFactory(p -> new MyTreeCell());
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(tree);
        return pane;
    }

    ObservableList rawItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "9-item", "8-item", "7-item", "6-item", 
            "5-item", "4-item", "3-item", "2-item", "1-item");

    protected TreeItem createSubTree(Object value) {
        TreeItem child = new TreeItem(value);
        child.getChildren().setAll((List<TreeItem>) rawItems.stream()
                .map(TreeItem::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(getContent());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `>` css syntax may help you. Meaning you can specify style of subcomponents

Comment: @eugener thanks for the suggestion, but doesn't make a difference (edited the css with the variant)

Comment: If I look into `modena.css` I see the following: `-fx-selection-bar: -fx-accent;` So why don't you use `-fx-background-color: -fx-accent;` directly instead if its working?

Comment: @eckig yeah, I know it looks like the same - but there seems to be a difference somehow/where. Why is the one working and the other not? I think there's a reason for the additional indirection (accent --> selection), so in order to go-for-the-highest-abstraction-available selection feels more appropriate Also note, that the text fill isn't updated with accent (it is with selection, even if it's not showing) ... Really strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is because `.label` doesn't have a rule where `-fx-background` is applied, so any value assigned to it won't affect any of the `Label` properties.

What's more, `Label` doesn't use a `-fx-background-color` property.

So an easy solution would be adding it:

```
.tree-text-only > .label {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background; 
}
```

Now you can apply all the style using only this "semantic" colors.

Note I've added also the case where the control doesn't have the focus:

```
/* 
 * remove the highlight from cell as a whole 
 */

/* Selected rows */
.tree-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-text-only:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background; 
}
/* Selected when control is not focused */
.tree-text-only:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background; 
}
/* focused cell (keyboard navigation) */
.tree-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-text-only:focused {
    -fx-cell-focus-inner-border: -fx-control-inner-background; 
}

/* 
 * highlight only the label
 */

// Add background color rule
.tree-text-only > .label {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background; 
}
/* Selected rows */
.tree-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-text-only:filled:selected > .label {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar; 
}
/* Selected when control is not focused */
.tree-text-only:filled:selected > .label {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar-non-focused;
}
/* focused cell (keyboard navigation) */
.tree-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-text-only:focused > .label {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar; 
}
```

Comment: silly me mixed up the rule with the color value - no wonder it didn't work ;-) Thanks again for your thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Again, I'm not 100% sure I understand your requirements, but following quick test works for me (`Label` is assigned to a graphic property of a `Button`):

```
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}

.button > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}

.button:pressed > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I noticed that hard-coding is working (probably didn't make it clear enough, sorry) - but why isn't it with a "semantic" color?